# Can not charge iPhone 5 from Macboook after Mavericks upgrade

Tags: charging

I have a Macbook and usually have it plugged into power.  I then connect iPhone 5 via USB port to charge the iPhone - it has worked for 3 years.  I updated my software to Mavericks last week and now the Macbook says "USB Device Disabled" "Unplug the device using too much power to re-enable USB device"

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Apple with the same problem and it turns out it was my cord.
You can test this by trying it with another cable you have.
If it then works you know it was the cable and you might have to buy a new one or if it's in warranty you can get it replaced for free.

Best Wishes!